# Inner join no muestra resultados - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
create table carrera(
clave_c int ,
nom_c varchar(50),
durac_c float,
constraint pk_clave_c primary key (clave_c)
)
--Tabla materia
create table materia(
clave_m int,
nom_m varchar(50),
cred_m float,
constraint pk_cm primary key (clave_m)
)

--Tabla profesor
create table profesor(
clave_p int,
nom_p varchar(50),
dir_p varchar(50),
tel_p bigint,
hor_p datetime,
constraint pk_cp primary key(clave_p)
)

--tabla alumno
create table alumno(
mat_alu int,
nom_alu varchar(50),
edad_alu int,
sem_alu int,
gen_alu varchar(50),
clave_c1 int,
constraint pk_calu primary key(mat_alu),
constraint fk_fc1 foreign key(clave_c1) references carrera(clave_c)
)

--Alumno-Profesor
create table alu_pro(
mat_alu1 int,
clave_p1 int,
constraint fk_falu1 foreign key(mat_alu1) references alumno(mat_alu),
constraint fk_fp1 foreign key(clave_p1) references profesor (clave_p)
)

--Materia-Alumno
create table mat_alu(
clave_m1 int,
mat_alu2 int,
constraint fk_fm1 foreign key(clave_m1)references materia (clave_m),
constraint fk_falu2 foreign key(mat_alu2)references alumno (mat_alu)
)
--Materia-Profesor
create table mat_pro(
clave_m2 int,
clave_p2 int,
constraint fk_fm2 foreign key (clave_m2) references materia(clave_m),
constraint fk_fp2 foreign key (clave_p2) references profesor(clave_p)
)


/*insertando datos*/

/*Insert*/
--Tabla carrera
insert into carrera values (3,'Diseño',3)

--Tabla materia
insert into materia values(3,'Dibujo',15)
insert into materia values(4,'Programación',20)

--Tabla alumno
insert into alumno values(2,'Sergio',19,7,'Hombre',2)
insert into alumno values(3,'Julieta',20,6,'Mujer',3)

--Alumno-Profesor
insert into alu_pro values(2,2)
insert into alu_pro values(3,2)

--Materia-ALumno
insert into mat_alu values(4,2)
insert into mat_alu values(3,3)
insert into mat_alu values(4,1)



insert into carrera values (1,'Derecho',3)
insert into carrera values (2,'Ingenieria en sistemas',4)

insert into materia values (1,'Matematicas',25)
insert into materia values (2,'Español',15)

insert into profesor values (1,'Laura Rosas','Calle Azul',567867,'7:00')
insert into profesor values (1,'Roberto Diaz','Calle Rosa',56473526,'9:00')

insert into alumno values(1,'Ana',18,6,'mujer',1)

insert into alu_pro values(1,2) 

insert into mat_alu values(1,1) 

insert into mat_pro values(2,2)
```

CONSULTA

```
select nom_alu,edad_alu,sem_alu,nom_c,nom_p,nom_m
from alumno 
inner join carrera on alumno.clave_c1=carrera.clave_c
inner join alu_pro on alu_pro.mat_alu1=alumno.mat_alu
inner join profesor on profesor.clave_p=alu_pro.clave_p1
inner join mat_alu on mat_alu.mat_alu2=alumno.mat_alu
inner join materia on materia.clave_m=mat_alu.clave_m1
```

OUTPUT

https://gyazo.com/a0fca5e7b8b84ff9c372e699e66ea73e

Comment: mmm.. y que resultados debe mostrar?? las relaciones si las agregas de a una, donde fallan? esta pregunta parece incompleta...

Comment: Este deberia ser el ouput.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener los resultados que buscas, donde dice:

```
insert into profesor values (1,'Roberto Diaz','Calle Rosa',56473526,'9:00')
```

debe decir:

```
insert into profesor values (2,'Roberto Diaz','Calle Rosa',56473526,'9:00')
```

Es MUY recomendable que pongas los IDs como PRIMARY KEYs.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema es el orden de los `inserts`, si es tal y como lo has añadido en el ejemplo falla porque intentas insertar valores de claves foráneas que aun no están insertados en las claves de la tablas a las que referencia. 
El segundo problema es añadir una hora en un campo `datetime`.
La `query` es correcta.

Ordenando los inserts y obviando en este ejemplo el campo de hor_p en la tabla porfesor se obtiene el resultado que esperas.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table carrera(
clave_c int ,
nom_c varchar(50),
durac_c float,
constraint pk_clave_c primary key (clave_c)
);

create table materia(
clave_m int,
nom_m varchar(50),
cred_m float,
constraint pk_cm primary key (clave_m)
);

create table profesor(
clave_p int,
nom_p varchar(50),
dir_p varchar(50),
tel_p bigint,
hor_p timestamp,
constraint pk_cp primary key(clave_p)
);

create table alumno(
mat_alu int,
nom_alu varchar(50),
edad_alu int,
sem_alu int,
gen_alu varchar(50),
clave_c1 int,
constraint pk_calu primary key(mat_alu),
constraint fk_fc1 foreign key(clave_c1) references carrera(clave_c)
);
create table alu_pro(
mat_alu1 int,
clave_p1 int,
constraint fk_falu1 foreign key(mat_alu1) references alumno(mat_alu),
constraint fk_fp1 foreign key(clave_p1) references profesor (clave_p)
);
create table mat_alu(
clave_m1 int,
mat_alu2 int,
constraint fk_fm1 foreign key(clave_m1)references materia (clave_m),
constraint fk_falu2 foreign key(mat_alu2)references alumno (mat_alu)
);
create table mat_pro(
clave_m2 int,
clave_p2 int,
constraint fk_fm2 foreign key (clave_m2) references materia(clave_m),
constraint fk_fp2 foreign key (clave_p2) references profesor(clave_p)
);


insert into carrera values (3,'Diseño',3);
insert into carrera values (1,'Derecho',3);
insert into carrera values (2,'Ingenieria en sistemas',4);

insert into materia values(3,'Dibujo',15);
insert into materia values(4,'Programación',20);
insert into materia values (1,'Matematicas',25);
insert into materia values (2,'Español',15);

insert into alumno values(2,'Sergio',19,7,'Hombre',2);
insert into alumno values(3,'Julieta',20,6,'Mujer',3);
insert into alumno values(1,'Ana',18,6,'mujer',1);

insert into profesor values (1,'Laura Rosas','Calle Azul',567867,null);
insert into profesor values (2,'Roberto Diaz','Calle Rosa',56473526,null);

insert into alu_pro values(2,2);
insert into alu_pro values(3,2);
insert into alu_pro values(1,2);

insert into mat_alu values(4,2);
insert into mat_alu values(3,3);
insert into mat_alu values(4,1);
insert into mat_alu values(1,1);

insert into mat_pro values(2,2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select nom_alu,edad_alu,sem_alu,nom_c,nom_p,nom_m
from alumno 
inner join carrera on alumno.clave_c1=carrera.clave_c
inner join alu_pro on alu_pro.mat_alu1=alumno.mat_alu
inner join profesor on profesor.clave_p=alu_pro.clave_p1
inner join mat_alu on mat_alu.mat_alu2=alumno.mat_alu
inner join materia on materia.clave_m=mat_alu.clave_m1;

| nom_alu | edad_alu | sem_alu | nom_c                  | nom_p        | nom_m        |
| ------- | -------- | ------- | ---------------------- | ------------ | ------------ |
| Sergio  | 19       | 7       | Ingenieria en sistemas | Roberto Diaz | Programación |
| Julieta | 20       | 6       | Diseño                 | Roberto Diaz | Dibujo       |
| Ana     | 18       | 6       | Derecho                | Roberto Diaz | Programación |
| Ana     | 18       | 6       | Derecho                | Roberto Diaz | Matematicas  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tw4afyjeTmDhDFnmsLdZPV/1)